# Replace characters within one line with sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file full of lines like:

```
ATOM  27576  OT2 TYR X 360      33.646  13.165  20.334  1.00  1.00      PROE
```

I want to convert it to be like:

```
ATOM  27576  OT2 TYR E 360      33.646  13.165  20.334  1.00  1.00      PROE
```

in other words, put the last letter from `PRO` where `X` stands. `X` is a constant within the file, but the `PRO` postfix varies. Is it possible to achieve it with a one line sed command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use capture groups:

**`sed 's/TYR X \(.*\)PRO\(.*\)$/TYR \2 \1PRO\2/'`**

```
$ echo "ATOM 27576 OT2 TYR X 360 33.646 13.165 20.334 1.00 1.00 PROE" | sed 's/TYR X \(.*\)PRO\(.*\)$/TYR \2 \1PRO\2/'
ATOM 27576 OT2 TYR E 360 33.646 13.165 20.334 1.00 1.00 PROE
```

Answer (score 1):

***awk*** solution would be more suitable for such case:

```
awk '{ $5=substr($NF,length($NF)) }1' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this sed:

```
sed -i '' -E 's/ X( .*PRO([A-Za-z]))/ \2\1/' file
ATOM 27576 OT2 TYR E 360 33.646 13.165 20.334 1.00 1.00 PROE
```

Comment: `-E` allows unescaped parens. I like the nested capture groups.  +1.

Answer (score 0):

Creative use of backreferences:

```
sed 's/^\(.\+\) X \(.\+\) \(...\)\(.\)$/\1 \4 \2 \3\4/'
```